# How do I split the years in this Pyspark mapreduce code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

I need to calculate for each word how many articles contain it in each year. I am stuck with how to split the years by words since I am keep getting the first words catenated with the dates as shown below.

```
['20191124,woman', 'stabbed', 'adelaide', 'shopping', 'centre', '20191204,economy', 'continue', 'teetering', 'edge', 'recession', '20200401,coronanom
ics', 'learnt', 'coronavirus', 'economy', '20200401,coronavirus', 'home', 'test', 'kits', 'selling', 'chinese', 'community', '20201015,coronavirus', 
'pacific', 'economy', 'foriegn', 'aid', 'china', '20201016,china', 'builds', 'pig', 'apartment', 'blocks', 'guard', 'swine', 'flu', '20211216,economy
', 'starts', 'bounce', 'unemployment', '20211224,online', 'shopping', 'rise', 'due', 'coronavirus', '20211229,china', 'close', 'encounters', 'elon', 
'musks']
```

**input:**

```
20191124,woman stabbed adelaide shopping centre
20191204,economy continue teetering edge recession
20200401,coronanomics learnt coronavirus economy
20200401,coronavirus home test kits selling chinese community
20201015,coronavirus pacific economy foriegn aid china
20201016,china builds pig apartment blocks guard swine flu
20211216,economy starts bounce unemployment
20211224,online shopping rise due coronavirus
20211229,china close encounters elon musks
```

**output** e.g,

```
adelaide    2019:1
aid    2020:1
apartment    2020:1
blocks    2020:1
...
```

Here is my following code for now

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

sc = SparkContext('local','frequencies')

text = sc.textFile('abcnews.txt')

word_year_pairs = text.flatMap(lambda line: [((word, line[:4]), 1) for word in line.split()])

word_counts = word_counter.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)

result = word_counts.map(lambda pair: (pair[0][0] + '\t' + pair[0][1] + ":" + str(pair[1])))

final = result.sortByKey()

final.saveAsTextFile('rdd.py')
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below implementation -

**Input Data**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

ser = """20191124,woman stabbed adelaide shopping centre
20191204,economy continue teetering edge recession
20200401,coronanomics learnt coronavirus economy
20200401,coronavirus home test kits selling chinese community
20201015,coronavirus pacific economy foriegn aid china
20201016,china builds pig apartment blocks guard swine flu
20211216,economy starts bounce unemployment
20211224,online shopping rise due coronavirus
20211229,china close encounters elon musks"""

pdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ser),names=['date', 'stringColumn'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

(df
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .csv("/test/tstfile.txt")
  )
```

**Required Output**

```
lines = sc.textFile("/test/tstfile.txt")

word_year_rdd = lines.flatMap(lambda line: [(word, line[:4]) for word in line.split()[1:]])

# Count the number of articles each word appears in for each year
word_year_count_rdd = word_year_rdd.map(lambda pair: (pair, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

# Format the output as (word, year:count) pairs
output_rdd = word_year_count_rdd.map(lambda pair: (pair[0][0], pair[0][1] + ":" + str(pair[1])))

# Print the output
output_rdd.toDF().orderBy("_1").show(5)

+---------+------+
|       _1|    _2|
+---------+------+
| adelaide|2019:1|
|      aid|2020:1|
|apartment|2020:1|
|   blocks|2020:1|
|   bounce|2021:1|
+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach with spark's high level dataframe API

```
# convert your rdd to DataFrame
df = text.toDF('string')

result = df.selectExpr(
    "substring(value, 0, 4) as year", 
    "explode(split(substring(value, 10), ' ')) as word"
).groupBy('word', 'year').count().orderBy('word')
```

Result

```
result.show()

+------------+----+-----+
|        word|year|count|
+------------+----+-----+
|    adelaide|2019|    1|
|         aid|2020|    1|
|   apartment|2020|    1|
|      blocks|2020|    1|
|      bounce|2021|    1|
|      builds|2020|    1|
|      centre|2019|    1|
|       china|2020|    2|
|       china|2021|    1|
|     chinese|2020|    1|
|       close|2021|    1|
|   community|2020|    1|
|    continue|2019|    1|
|coronanomics|2020|    1|
| coronavirus|2021|    1|
| coronavirus|2020|    3|
|         due|2021|    1|
|     economy|2020|    2|
|     economy|2019|    1|
|     economy|2021|    1|
+------------+----+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```